# SQLite database as text file?

Tags: database, sqlite

I was thinking of storing SQLite database file in version control (git), also i want to see the diff of the database file between different versions.

Can we configure SQLite to store it's data in a readable text format(Given i do not store any binary data in the db)? So that i do not have to dump the data to a text file to see the difference. Say for example a CSV format.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native SQLite database file format is always binary, but you could use the `.dump` command of the `sqlite3` command-line tool to create a textual representation of the database.